# How can I find the last revision where I have merged from a branch?

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to find the revision number in `default`, from which I have merged into current branch.

If there were several pulls from `default`, I'm interested in the latest one.

Current brunch is not merged into `default` yet.

---

I'll explain why I need this revision. I only need to find all the edits made in current brunch. I pulled from `default` several times (without conflicts), so my idea is to diff between branch head and the revision I'm asking for.

My [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290726/how-to-list-files-changed-in-given-branch) was formulated badly. I do not need diff between the head of default, because the head if far away now.

Comment: Something like this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863065/how-to-view-diff-between-head-of-local-repository-and-head-of-remote-repository

Answer (score 4):

You want:

```
hg log --rev 'ancestor(default, BRANCHNAME)'
```

That says: "Show the the single changeset that is the most recent ancestor of both the current head of branch BRANCHNAME and the current head of branch `default`.  Which essentially gives you the last time default was merged into BRANCHNAME.